# Particular union of well ordered sets that is well ordered

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Suppose $X$ has a partial ordering $\leq$. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$, we say that $A\leq B$ if and only if $A \subseteq B$ and for $b \in B$, $b \leq a \in A$ implies $b \in A$. Now, if $F$ is a collection of well ordered subsets (by the ordering on $X$) of $X$ such that for $C, D \in F$ either $C\leq D$ or $ D\leq C$, then prove that the union $\bigcup_{C \in F} C$ is well ordered. I can prove that the union is totally ordered, but I cannot find a least element for a subset of the union. How would I go about that?

Comment: Mind sharing how you proved that the union is totally ordered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I misread the problem as saying that $F$ was a well-ordered collection (under the order defined on $\mathcal{P}(X)$) of well-ordered subsets of $X$.

<strike>**Hint.** Let $R$ be a nonempty subset of $\cup_{C\in F} C$. Let $I=\{D\in F\mid D\cap R\neq \varnothing\}$.</strike>

Since $I$ is nonempty, and is a subset of $F$, it has a least element $D_0$. And $R\cap D_0\neq\varnothing$. Try the least element of $R\cap D_0$.

---

This is a bit subtler. If $C$ and $D$ are well-ordered subsets of $X$, and $C\leq D$, then $C$ is what is called an **initial segment** of $D$. What you are asked to prove is that if you have a collection of well-ordered subsets of a poset $X$, with the property that given any two sets in the collection one is an initial segment of the other, then the union is well-ordered.

We may assume that the union is nonempty (for if it is empty, it is trivially well-ordered). Let $R$ be a nonempty subset of $\cup_{C\in F}C$. Let $r\in R$. Then there exists $C_r\in F$ such that $r\in C_r$, and so in particular, $R\cap C_r\neq\varnothing$. Let $r_0$ be the least element of $R\cap C_r$, which exists since $C_r$ is well-ordered.

I claim that $r_0$ is the least element of $R$. Indeed, let $s\in R$; then there exists $C_s\in F$ such that $s\in C_s$. Now, either $C_r$ is an initial segment of $C_s$ (that is, $C_r\leq C_s)$ or $C_s$ is an initial segment of $C_r$ (that is, $C_s\leq C_r$).

If $C_s\leq C_r$, then $C_s\subseteq C_r$, and hence $s\in C_s\cap R \subseteq C_r\cap R$. Since $r_0$ is the least element of $C_r\cap R$, then $r_0\leq s$.

If $C_r\leq C_s$, then $s\leq r_0$ implies that $s\in C_r$ (since $r_0\in C_r$ and $s\leq r_0$), and hence $s\in C_r\cap R$, and thus $r_0\leq s$, so in fact we have $r_0=s$.

Either way, $r_0\leq s$. This proves that $r_0$ is the least element of $R$.

Thus, $\cup_{C\in F} C$ is well-ordered.

Comment: Isn't this just a dodgy way of shifting the problem? Why would $I$ have a least element?

Comment: Hmmm... I seem to have read that $F$ was a well-ordered collection. But apparently that is not what you said... Give me a minute.

Comment: Dear Arturo, I don't have enough reputation  to accept your answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @user651717: My understanding is that you can *always* accept answers to your questions. Did you try?

Comment: Why does $s \leq r_0$ imply that $s \in C_r$? I'm imagining the case $R = \{3, 4\}$ and we have the part of the chain $C_r = \{1, 2, 4\} \subset \{1, 2, 3, 4\} = C_s$. Then $s = 3 \leq 4 = r_0 \in C_r \cap R$.

Comment: @MathSimp: Read the conditions: these are what are called "initial segments". $A\leq B$ means that $A\subseteq B$, and if $b\in B$, $a\in A$, and $b\leq a$, then $b\in A$. Your sets $C_r$ and $C_s$ do not have this property, since $3\in C_s$, $4\in C_r$, and $3\leq 4$, but $3\notin C_r$. Tha means that $C_r\nleq C_s$ under the given definition, so your example does not apply.

Comment: Ah yes, so then we must have that $s \in C_r$ if $s \leq r_0$, my apologies. I came across your answer because I've been struggling on a similar question. I'm not sure this is what I was looking for though

Comment: @MathSimp: If you've done your due diligence and believe you cannot find an adequate question, then do feel free to post your question. You may link to related questions you found and indicate why you believe they do not apply to forestall your question being closed as a duplicate.