# Partial ordering with respect to being an initial segment or continuation according to Halmos

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

There is an exercise in "Naive Set Theory" by Halmos given as (Sec. 17, p. 68):

> A subset $A$ of a partially ordered set $X$ is *cofinal* in $X$ in case for each element $x$ of $X$ there exists an element $a$ of $A$ such that $x \leqq a$.
>   Prove that every totally ordered set has a cofinal well ordered subset.

I'm checking a sketch of the proof from the [Answer by Brian M. Scott on Luka Horvat's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112374/164272) and it seems intuitively valid to me, but I stumble on trying to strictly prove the very first step from it:

> Let $\langle X,\le\rangle$ be a non-empty linear order. If $X$ has a maximum element $x_0$, then $\{x_0\}$ is a well-ordered cofinal subset, so assume that $X$ has no largest element. Let 
>   $$\mathscr{W}=\{W\subseteq X:\langle W,\le\rangle\text{ is a well-order}\}\;,$$
>   and define a relation $\preceq$ on $\mathscr{W}$ by setting $W_0\preceq W_1$ if and only if $W_0$ is an initial segment of $W_1$.
>   - Prove that $\preceq$ partially orders $\mathscr{W}$.

To show that the relation $\preceq$ thus defined is a partial order, I have started from trying to show that it is reflexive, i.e.

For $w \in \mathscr W$, it is that $w \preceq w$ (or, $w$ is an initial segment of $w$)

However from Halmos' definition of an initial segment, I think it's impossible because $w$ being an initial segment of $w$ would mean that $\exists z \in w$ s.t. $w = \{ x \in w: x \le z \}$ (if we understand "initial segment" as a "weak initial segment"), and thus, that $w$ should have the largest element. Thus for all sets in $\mathscr W$ which don't have the largest element, the relation won't be reflexive. I think that examples of such could be constructed, i.e. a set $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...\}$ is well ordered, but it won't be an initial segment of itself due to the lack of the greatest element.

To put it short, my question is: how can a partial ordering with respect to being an initial segment or a continuation exist if it seems to violate the reflexivity condition?

### Addendum

As I see it, a similar problem would occur when we talk about *partial orderings with respect to continuation* as *continuation* is a special case of an *initial segment* according to Halmos. Halmos himself talks about some partial orderings with respect to continuation in Sec. 17 of the book, so the question arises not only in a context of the [aforementioned answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1112374/164272)

### The definitions from the book

In "Naive Set Theory" by Halmos, **continuation** is defined as:

> a well ordered set $A$ is a *continuation* of a well ordered set $B$, if, in the first place, $B$ is a subset of $A$, if, in fact, $B$ is an initial segment of $A$, and if, finally, the ordering of the elements in $B$ is the same as their ordering in $A$

the definition of **initial segment** as given in one of the previous chapters of the book is:

> if $X$ is a partially ordered set, and if $a \in X$, the set $ \{ x \in X: x < a \} $ is the *initial segment* determined by $a$

Comment: Accept the weak version or make the order A is a lower subset  of B.

Comment: @WilliamElliot thank you, it seems to me that the definition of "Lower subset" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set should work. The whole chapter "Well Ordering" (that contains the Well Ordering Theorem) is filled with p.o. sets with respects to continuation. I will try to follow the arguments in the text reading it as a "p.o. set with respect to being a lower subset" according to that Wikipedia definition